# Is changing parent process necessary when daemonize a process?

Tags: linux, daemon

I am reading about daemonizing a process at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29#Creation

> In a strictly technical sense, a Unix-like system process is a daemon
>   when its parent process terminates and the daemon is assigned the init
>   process (process number 1) as its parent process and has no
>   controlling terminal. However, more commonly, a daemon may be any
>   background process, whether a child of the init process or not.
>
> On a Unix-like system, the common method for a process to become a
>   daemon, when the process is started from the command line or from a
>   startup script such as an init script or a SystemStarter script,
>   involves:
>
> 1. Dissociating from the controlling tty
> 2. Becoming a session leader
> 3. Becoming a process group leader
> 4. Executing as a background task by forking and exiting (once or twice). This is required sometimes for the process to become a session
>      leader. It also allows the parent process to continue its normal
>      execution.
> 5. Setting the root directory (/) as the current working directory so that the process does not keep any directory in use that may be on
>      a mounted file system (allowing it to be unmounted).
> 6. Changing the umask to 0 to allow open(), creat(), and other operating system calls to provide their own permission masks and not
>      to depend on the umask of the caller
> 7. Closing all inherited files at the time of execution that are left open by the parent process, including file descriptors 0, 1 and 2
>      for the standard streams (stdin, stdout and stderr). Required files
>      will be opened later.
> 8. Using a logfile, the console, or /dev/null as stdin, stdout, and stderr
>
> If the process is started by a super-server daemon, such as inetd,
>   launchd, or systemd, the super-server daemon will perform those
>   functions for the process[5][6][7] (except for old-style daemons not
>   converted to run under systemd and specified as Type=forking[7] and
>   "multi-threaded" datagram servers under inetd[5]).

1. Is there a step there that changes the parent process of a process
   to be daemonized? It seems to me none of the steps does that?

   Is changing parent process necessary when daemonize a process?
2. After changing the parent process of a process (**a process not necessarily
   to be daemonized)**, can the process be associated to the controlling
   tty of the new parent process? (The purpose of the question is to
   see whether "keeping a process disassociated from the the
   controlling tty of the new parent process" is a necessary condition
   of "changing the parent process of the process".)

See my related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266565/daemonize-a-process-in-shell

Thanks.

Comment: Use [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

The parent of a Unix process can't be changed by the process itself. The typical method of creating a daemon involves a `fork` call (which creates the process that will become the daemon). The initial process then exits, and the newly-orphaned child process will be inherited by the `init` process which becomes it's new parent. That's handled in step 4. The only thing `init` will do is wait for all it's children to exit. `init` doesn't have a controlling TTY, so once inherited by `init` the daemon can't become associated with a controlling TTY anymore. The main reason to become disassociated is to prevent signals generated from the TTY (hangups and control-C's etc.) from getting to the daemon.

There are two ways daemons are usually run:

1. From a shell script. The script runs the daemon's executable with the `&` operator at the end of the command to put the daemon into the background, possibly with I/O redirection to set the daemon's stdin, stdout and/or stderr, and then exits leaving the daemon without a parent. Running an executable from the shell involves the shell doing a `fork` followed by an `exec` in the child process of the executable to be run.
2. The daemon program has an option to daemonize itself. When run with that option it does a `fork` followed in the child process by an `exec` of itself with an appropriate set of arguments. The parent will normally exit after the `fork` since the work it's been asked to do is done. If it doesn't, the child process needs an extra `fork` to give it a parent that can exit. NB: this is why so many programs that normally run as daemons can be run directly without becoming a daemon, the "become a daemon" option causes the child process to close stdin/stdout/stderr and then just `exec` it's own executable without the "become a daemon" option.

Comment: Thanks. In the first way of running daemons, does "The script runs the daemon's executable with the & operator at the end of the command to put the daemon into the background" allow the parent "then exits leaving the daemon without a parent"?  If I am correct, backgrounding a process is not sufficient to allow its parent to exit without itself exiting. We need to disown or nohup the process, besides backgrounding it, so that when its parent exits, it will not exit.

Comment: I've never found SIGHUP to be propagated to children, likely because `&` puts the child process in it's own process group so signals to the parent don't get delivered to the child. If the parent had a TTY as stdin, the child's stdin wasn't redirected and the child didn't close stdin quickly enough, the child might receive SIGHUP from the TTY if the parent exits and causes the TTY to be destroyed. Redirecting the child's stdin to /dev/null's so automatic I can't recall the last time I ran into that problem but it can happen.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

Your list does not mention explicitly [setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html).

[MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) has a [legacy/daemon.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/legacy/daemon.c) which forks twice and do `setsid`